# Deserialize JSON attribute to class

Tags: c#, json, deserialization

For the most part my JSON deserialization seems to work fine except for the last attribute that I added.
I have the following JSON string.
If I keep my class property type as string for the attribute httpVerb, the deserialization works just fine. 
But if I keep class property type as System.Net.HttpMethod for the attribute httpVerb then the deserialization is failing.
I really hate to create another enum as the HTTP verbs are already defined in the HttpMethod class.

Can someone help?

```
{
    "httpTest": {
        "ignoreCertificateErrors": false, 
        "successHTTPStatusCodes": [ 200 ], 
        "httpVerb": "GET"
    }
}

public class HttpTest
{
    public bool ignoreCertificateErrors { get; set; }
    public List<HttpStatusCode> successHTTPStatusCodes { get; set; }
    public HttpMethod httpVerb { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public HttpTest httpTest { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: A string is not an object.  So naturally the deserialization is failing.

Comment: How would you handle a situation like this David? Obviously I can keep this as a string but I prefer a strong type without having to re-inventing the wheels.

Comment: Unfortunately, you are going to need to do some post-processing of your deserialization. The only reason `successHTTPStatusCodes` is deserialized properly is because `HttpStatusCode` is an enum in `System.Net`, whereas `HttpMethod` is its on class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to deserialize your json verb as a string.  That said, you can return the corresponding HttpMethod instance to preserve your strong typing with the addition of another property.

```
public class HttpTest
{
    public bool ignoreCertificateErrors { get; set; }
    public List<HttpStatusCode> successHTTPStatusCodes { get; set; }
    public string httpVerb { get; set; }
    public HttpMethod HttpMethodInstance { 
        get { return new HttpMethod(httpVerb); }
    }
}
```

If your verb is a valid verb, you can use it to instantiate a new instance of HttpMethod